# How to delete item form list?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html code to add some orders, the customer is going to choose item from `combobox` and write its Amount in `textbox`,then click on `add` button then he can choose another item and then write its amount and so on,i need to add the `order details` after each click on the button and adding `remove` button beside to allow the user to remove it from the order if he wants,how can it be done?

```
<div>
    <label class="arrow-right"> Category Name:</label>
</div>
<div>                           
    <select class="SelectStyle" style="width:95%;margin-left:4px;border:0;" name="CategoryName" id="CategoryName" onchange="GetCatType(this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerHTML)">
        <option value="">Select Category Name</option>
            <!--populate value using php-->
            <?php
             $stmt ="SELECT distinct Category_Name FROM Categories";
             foreach ($conn->query($stmt) as $row) {
            ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"><?php echo $row['Category_Name'];?></option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="arrow-right"> Category Type:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="SelectStyle" style="width:95%;margin-left:4px;border:0;" name="CategoryType" id="CategoryType" >
    <option value="">Select Category Type</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label> &nbsp;&nbsp;Amount:</label>
    <input type="text" id="Amounttxt" style="background-color:white;color:rgb(16,29,73);font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;width:90px;height:28px;" name="Amounttxt"> &nbsp;<label>Kg</label>
    <button id="Add" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-left: 5px;" onclick="AddAmount()">Add</button>
</div>
<div>
    <label class="arrow-right"> Order Details:</label><br>
    <ul id="OrderDetails"></ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
      <div>
        <button id="AddOrder" type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:5px;" onclick="AddNewOrder()">Add Order</button><br>
      </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
 function AddAmount()
  {
  var sel = document.getElementById('CategoryName');
  var CatName = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;
  var select = document.getElementById('CategoryType');
  var CatType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  var catSel = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
  var AmountTxt = document.getElementById('Amounttxt').value;

   if(catSel!='' && AmountTxt!='')
    {
          var OrderDetails=document.getElementById('OrderDetails');
          var existingItems = OrderDetails.childNodes;

            if(existingItems.length>0){
                for(i=0; i < existingItems.length; i++){
                        if(existingItems[i].getAttribute('cattype')==CatType){
                            alert('Item already Added');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
        var current=document.getElementById('OrderDetails').innerHTML;
        var new_item='<li class="OrderDetails" catname=' + CatName + ' cattype='+CatType +' amountTxt='+AmountTxt+'>'+ CatName + " " +CatType + " : " + AmountTxt + ' Kg <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="removeit(this)"></i></li>';
        alert(new_item);
        document.getElementById('OrderDetails').innerHTML=current+new_item;
        document.getElementById('Amounttxt').value="";
   }

   else{
   alert('values are incomplete');
   }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function AddAmount()
   {
      var select = document.getElementById('CategoryType');
      var CatType = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
    var catSel = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
      var AmountTxt = document.getElementById('Amounttxt').value;
    if(catSel!='' && AmountTxt!=''){
   var OrderDetails=document.getElementById('OrderDetails')
   var existingItems = OrderDetails.childNodes;
  if(existingItems.length>0){
   for(i=0; i < existingItems.length; i++){
     if(existingItems[i].getAttribute('cattype')==CatType){
      alert('Item already Added')
         return false
      }
    }
   }
     

    var current=document.getElementById('OrderDetails').innerHTML
    var new_item='<p cattype='+CatType +' amountTxt='+AmountTxt+'>'+CatType + " : " + AmountTxt + ' Kg <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" onclick="removeit(this)"></i></p>';
    document.getElementById('OrderDetails').innerHTML=current+new_item;


     
 document.getElementById('CategoryType').value="";
 document.getElementById('Amounttxt').value="";
    }
    
    else{
    alert('values are incomplete');
    }
      
   }

function removeit(obj){
 
 var answer= confirm("Do you want to remove")
 if(answer){
  obj.parentNode.remove()
 }
}
function showSummary(){
var OrderDetails=document.getElementById('OrderDetails')
var existingItems = OrderDetails.childNodes;
  if(existingItems.length>0){
   for(i=0; i < existingItems.length; i++){
  alert("Selected Item is "+existingItems[i].getAttribute('cattype') +" with quantity "+ existingItems[i].getAttribute('amountTxt')+" kg")
 }
  }
  else{
 alert("no Item Added")
  }
}
```

```html
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <div>
        <label class="arrow-right"> Category Type:</label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <select class="SelectStyle" style="width:200px;margin-left:4px;border:0;" name="CategoryType" id="CategoryType" >
           <option value="">Select Category Type</option>
           <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
        </select>
    </div>                  
    </div>
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div><label> &nbsp;&nbsp;Amount:</label></div>
    <div>
        <input type="text" id="Amounttxt" style="background-color:white;color:rgb(16,29,73);font-weight:bold;padding-left:5px;width:80px;height:28px;" name="Amounttxt"> &nbsp;<label>Kg</label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div><br></div>
    <div>
       <button id="Add" type="button" class="btn btn-success" onclick="AddAmount()">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-12">
    <label class="arrow-right"> Order Details:</label><br>
    <label id="OrderDetails"></label>
    <button onclick="showSummary()"> Show Summary</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Deep3015..Perfect that is exactly what i need...Thanks :)

Comment: can you help me to retrieve the all the values in `orderdetails` after clicking on another button?

Comment: @Deep3015..Thanks :), Can you tell me how to prevent the user from adding the category type twice ?

Comment: @Newdeveloper update as per requirement. Feeling good to help you :-)

Comment: @Deep3015...Thanks alot :)..it works here in `snippet` fine but not in my code :( i really don't know why

Comment: @New developer give me jsfiddle link , so I can look the problem

Comment: @Deep3015..i noticed that when i am filling the combo box from database it isn't working and if i am filling it at the beginning it works!!...i have updated the code above,can you help me in that?

Comment: @New developer , check if data is coming from database. you can check by  print_r($row) .After putting static html option in both select box your code is working fine

Comment: @Deep3015...the select boxes are filled correctly from database,,i can't find the problem :(

Comment: @Deep3015..I found the problem :)...It was the spaces between the name of the category type...Thanks alot for your help

Comment: Keep learning from these errors.also you can use console.log(variable) or alert(variable) to see what is value of variable.this helps a lot while debugging

Answer (score 0):

Create a js array in which you store the different lines that you want to display in the OrderDetails.
Everytime something changes you can 'redraw' the content of that field based on the values in the array. So when an item is removed, remove it from the array and call the funtion that redraws the innterHTML of the label/field in which you want to display it.

However, I must say, this really feels like a strange approach. I do not know what you exactly are trying to do, but maybe look around to see how other systems/sites/tools handle these kind of use cases.